# FLTK - throw an exception inside handle

Tags: c++, exception, fltk

I’m using FLTK 1.3.3 and I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```
class MyWidget: public Fl_Widget
{
private:
  virtual int handle(int) override;
  void ParseClipboardText(const char *);

public:
  // ...
};

int MyWidget::handle(int event)
{
if (event==FL_PASTE)
  {
  ParseClipboardText(Fl::event_text()); // May throw
  return 1;
  }
return Fl_Widget::handle(event);
}
```

The problem is that if an exception is thrown, `handle` doesn’t return and the clipboard text doesn’t seem to be released (I can no longer copy to the clipboard).

I tried a possible workaround without success:

```
class MyWidget: public Fl_Widget
{
private:
  std::string textBuffer;

private:
  static void MyCallBack(Fl_Widget *,void *);
  virtual int handle(int) override;
  void ParseClipboardText(const std::string &);

public:
  MyWidget();
};

MyWidget::MyWidget()
{
callback(&MyCallBack);
when(FL_WHEN_CHANGED);
// ...
}

int MyWidget::handle(int event)
{
if (event==FL_PASTE)
  {
  textBuffer= Fl::event_text();
  set_changed();
  return 1;
  }
return Fl_Widget::handle(event);
}

void MyWidget::MyCallBack(Fl_Widget *pw,void *)
{
  MyWidget *pmw= static_cast<MyWidget *>(pw);

  pmw->ParseClipboardText(pmw->textBuffer);
}
```

Is there a way of scheduling a callback function to be called immediately after `handle` returns?

Comment: Try putting a try-catch around the section that is throwing.

Comment: @cup I’m afraid I can’t. I want to catch the exception, display an appropriate widget, and handle the associated events.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution seems to involve calling `redraw` (or better `damage`) in `handle` and then call the potentially throwing function in the `draw` method, once `handle` has been completed.

The problem of not releasing the clipboard contents occurs under Windows, but not under Linux.